# Boolean Search Operator Optimization, respecting quoted terms

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Looking for the most optimal way to parse a complex search string and reduce it to have 1 Boolean operator between terms. The operators are OR, AND, NOR.

Ex:
1. OR AND NOR NOR AND AND Fred OR NOR AND Wilma NOR AND AND Barney OR “The and AND Flintstones” OR AND NOR NOR AND AND

OR AND NOR nor AND AND Fred OR NOR AND Wilma NOR and AND Barney OR “The and AND Flintstones” OR and NOR NOR AND AND (added Mar-05-2014)

Result:

Fred OR Wilma NOR Barney OR "The and AND Flintstones"

Note: I am looking for PHP code implementation.

Comment: I suggest don't followed by http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Your result : Fred OR Wilma NOR "“The and AND Flintstones”, but there is word in resut: Barney? you make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to read the input word-by-word and process it in a state machine.

Something along the lines:

```
define("STATE_DEFAULT", 0); // we're in regular text
define("STATE_OPERATOR", 1);  // we found operator (AND|OR|NOR)
define("STATE_QUOTE",2); // we're inside quoted text

$input = 'OR AND NOR NOR AND AND Fred OR NOR AND Wilma NOR AND AND Barney OR "The and AND Flintstones" OR AND NOR NOR AND AND';

// check if a word is an operator... used in multiple places 
function _is_op($word) { return preg_match("/^(AND|OR|NOR)$/i", $word); }

$words = explode(" ", $input);
$words_count = count($words);
$state = STATE_DEFAULT;

for($i=0; $i<$words_count; ++$i)
{
    $word = $words[$i];

    switch($state)
    {
         case STATE_QUOTE:
             if(substr($word,-1)=='"') $state = STATE_DEFAULT;
             break;

         case STATE_OPERATOR:
             if(_is_op($word))
             {
                 unset($words[$i]);
                 break;
             }

         case STATE_DEFAULT:
         default:
            $state = STATE_DEFAULT;
             if($word[0] == '"')
                 $state = STATE_QUOTE;
             elseif(_is_op($word))
                 $state = STATE_OPERATOR;
             break;
    }
}

// if we removed some words, count()-1 is no longer the last element
$words = array_values($words);

// strip operators from start and end
if(_is_op($words[0])) array_shift($words);
if(_is_op($words[count($words)-1])) array_pop($words);

$output = implode(" ", $words);
```

While it might be possible to do this using *regular expressions*, it'd be complex and quite unmanageable .

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help:

$words = explode (" ", 'OR AND NOR NOR AND AND Fred OR NOR AND Wilma NOR AND AND Barney OR "The and AND Flintstones" OR AND NOR NOR AND AND');

$arrayOperators = array('OR', 'AND', 'NOR');

$flag = false;
foreach($words as $key => $word){
    if($flag && in_array($word, $arrayOperators)){
          unset($words[$key]);
    }elseif(in_array($word, $arrayOperators)){
       if($key != 0){
          $resultArray[] = $word;
        }
        $flag = true;

    }else{
        $resultArray[] = $word;
        $flag = false;
    }
}
end($resultArray);
$lastKey = key($resultArray);
if(in_array($resultArray[$lastKey], $arrayOperators)){
   array_pop($resultArray);
}

var_dump(implode(' ', $resultArray));
```

**Result:**

```
string(53) "Fred OR Wilma NOR Barney OR "The and AND Flintstones""
```

Comment: I don't see any special treatment for quoted text here ;) the fact you get the desired result is only because `"The and AND Flinstones"` is considered having one operator inside (and quoted text should not be parsed for operators)... Well that, and (because you're checking for operators by `in_array`), you make the operator case sensitive, but maybe that's okay ;)

Comment: I add to text more operators and everything work fine

Comment: What will be the result of this code running on this input: `"The and AND AND AND Flintstones"` ?

Comment: string(23) "The and AND Flintstones"

Comment: Exactly... and it should not be altered at all (because the text is quoted)

Comment: Why uou think so, I did not see thta OP asking this

Comment: The questions is named "Boolean Search Operator Optimization, **respecting quoted terms**"

Comment: All of these suggests are awesome thank you so kindly. 

Please note; $words = explode (" ", 'OR AND NOR NOR AND AND Fred OR NOR AND Wilma NOR AND AND Barney OR "The and AND Flintstones" OR AND NOR NOR AND AND');
Results in: 
Array ( [0] => OR [1] => AND [2] => NOR [3] => NOR [4] => AND [5] => AND [6] => Fred [7] => OR [8] => NOR [9] => AND [10] => Wilma [11] => NOR [12] => AND [13] => AND [14] => Barney [15] => OR [16] => "The [17] => and [18] => AND [19] => Flintstones" [20] => OR [21] => AND [22] => NOR [23] => NOR [24] => AND [25] => AND )

Comment: Continued from above. How is index 17 and 18 not removed in Sergio's cool state machine posted Feb 26.

Comment: @MarkusAurelius they are not removed because `$words[17]` is lowercase, and hence is not considered an operator by this code...

Comment: Hi poncha, and $word[18] is upper case. Note: I have change this contraints now, to include keyword to be both upper and lowercase, which is likely in a typical search.